# why i get a lot of errors when i use truffle?

Tags: truffle

Seems that i have a lot of lost dependencies for example installing sha3 errors:

```
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sha3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin
\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program
 Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mo
dules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mod
ules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\grac
eful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\sha3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\system32\pac
kage.json'
npm WARN system32 No description
npm WARN system32 No repository field.
npm WARN system32 No README data
npm WARN system32 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fse
vents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"
})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sha3@1.2.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sha3@1.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mirror\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-06T15_05_03
_287Z-debug.log
```

Always install nodegyp again show errors, again if i install web3 the same errors, maybe is because i must to use linux instead of windows? Compiling errors again with web3

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to install python and add it to your path.